# Lipschitz bounds for $a\|x-y\|+b$

Tags: calculus, analysis, lipschitz-functions

During my attempt to formulate a Lipschitz bound in a course extra material, I encountered an expression in the form $a\|x-y\|+b$, with $a,b>0$. Is it possible to adjust the expression to a form of the type $C(a,b)\|x-y\|$, so that $C(a,b)$ serves as Lipschitz constant?

Comment: Think about what happens when $x$ and $y$ get very close together

Comment: I would get $b<0$, contradicting $b>0$, thus no, thanks!

Comment: @JimmyK4542, by the way, I have written a more comprehensive post regarding the problem I am trying to solve, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4881454/lipschitz-bound-for-matrix-vector-functions