# Lipschitz bound for matrix-vector functions

Tags: matrices, vectors, upper-lower-bounds, lipschitz-functions

Given $A(x)$, with $A:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^{m\times n}}$ and $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$, with $\mathbf{f}$ Lipschitz, is it possible to derive a Lipschitz bound of $A(x)\mathbf{f}(x): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$?

I thought of proceeding as follows,
$$
\begin{align}
\|A(x)\mathbf{f}(x)-A(y)\mathbf{f}(y)\| &= \|A(x)\mathbf{f}(x) - A(x)\mathbf{f}(y) + A(x)\mathbf{f}(y) -A(y)\mathbf{f}(y)\|\\
&\leq \|A(x)\|L_f\|x- y\|+ \|(A(x)-A(y))\mathbf{f}(y)\|\\
& \dots\\
& \leq L_{A,\mathbf{f}}\|x-y\|
\end{align}
$$
but from the last expression (right before the dots) I do not see a viable way of proceeding, even by adding additional requirements.

*Edit* (thanks to @MoisheKohan for pointing out):
The problem stated above is a reframing of my original problem, where $A(x)=J_{\mathbf{g}}^+(x)$ is the pseudo inverse of the Jacobian $J_{\mathbf{g}}$ of a function $\mathbf{g}:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$. Assuming the matrix-valued function is Lipschitz would obviously solve the problem, but I don't know whether it is a reasonable assumption).

(Trying to reason in a general manner, I thought of reframing the last line as $a\|x-y\|+b$, with $a,b>0$, for which searching for a bound of the type $C(a,b)\|x-y\|$ would lead to a contradiction $b<0$ in the case $\|x-y\|\rightarrow 0$, but this does not take into account the fact that $b=b(x,y)$ as in the original problem. I am a bit stuck.)

Comment: Is #A# Lipschitz as well?

Comment: Added a line about $A$, in my original problem $A$ is the pseudo inverse of the Jacobian..., thus I don't know if it would make sense to talk about Lipschitzness of the vector-matrix function defined by the inverse of the Jacobian

Comment: You should explain in detail what $A$ is: you wrote two contradictory things about it (pseudoinverse of Jacobian and pseudoinverse of inverse Jacobian).

Comment: Edit your question then and add a reference to the notion of the pseudoinverse. As for your question, the answer is surely negative without further assumptions on the function $g$.

Comment: Edited, thanks for pointing out. I understand, what type of assumptions would help?

Comment: Being globally  Lipschitz is a very restrictive assumption., just saying.  For example, even the product of two identity functions is not globally Lipschitz because $y=x^2$ is not Lipschitz. So for a counter-example, craft your $g$ such that you get a term like  $x^2$ in $Af$.

Comment: For instance if $g$ has no critical points and your Lipschitz condition is local not global. But you have to go back to the problem you are trying so solve and check what restrictions on $g$ you actually have. I cannot guess this for you.

Comment: @MoisheKohan $g$ is a Lipschitz map

Comment: Then it is not even everywhere differentiable.

Comment: Almost everywhere by Rademacher, right. Eventually, I can restrict the requirements on $g$.

Comment: The reality is that even if you assume that $n=m=1$, $f$ is nonzero constant and $g$ is infinitely differentiable with compact support, you will not even get continuity, let alone Lipschitz property, for your function.